# Oracle SQL multi-level pivot groups

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

EDIT: To those saying this is a clear & obvious "No": Sure, I figured that was the case, and hierarchical headers were beyond the scope of SQL query results. However, apart from some Mysql work, I've just made the jump from an old legacy SQL Server 2000 platform to Oracle 12g, and finding things there that I could never have imagined doing in SS 2000, so I thought I'd ask. I write loads of SQL to feed my presentation layer in a few report creation systems, and so I'm exploring this leap forward in capabilities from SS 2000.

I may be asking too much of the Oracle Pivot function, but this is what I'm trying to do. I can pivot at a single level but I want a hierarchy of column grouping with multiple measures the way you could easily do in a spreadsheet crosstab. Here's sample data & desired output:

```
select * 
from(
   select 'A' rws, 'X' cols, 2 v1, 90 v2 from dual union
   select 'A' rws, 'Y' cols, 25 v1, 112 v2 from dual union
   select 'A' rws, 'Y' cols, 7 v1, 64 v2 from dual union
   select 'B' rws, 'X' cols, 4 v1, 117 v2 from dual union
   select 'B' rws, 'Y' cols, 46 v1, 32 v2 from dual union
   select 'B' rws, 'X' cols, 0 v1, 18 v2 from dual
)
```

Here is the output I would like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|             A              |              B             |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|      X      |      Y       |      X       |      Y      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  v1  |  v2  |  v1  |  v2   |  v1  |  v2   |  v1  |  v2  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |  90  |  32  |  176  |  4   |  135  |  46  |  32  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Not possible. For one thing, in a relational database there is only one level of "headers" - you need different levels, and that is already not possible, even ignoring your desire to have different numbers of headers at each level. This is definitely a report **presentation** issue; you should "ask" your report preparation software to do this, not SQL. SQL only gives you the data, accurately and quickly; it is not written to understand things like "hierarchy of headers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can pivot data as you want, but you need to format header yourself, since onviously Oracle return standard table data:

```
select * 
from(
   select 'A' rws, 'X' cols, 2 v1, 90 v2 from dual union
   select 'A' rws, 'Y' cols, 25 v1, 112 v2 from dual union
   select 'A' rws, 'Y' cols, 7 v1, 64 v2 from dual union
   select 'B' rws, 'X' cols, 4 v1, 117 v2 from dual union
   select 'B' rws, 'Y' cols, 46 v1, 32 v2 from dual union
   select 'B' rws, 'X' cols, 0 v1, 18 v2 from dual
) t
pivot 
(
   max(v1) as v1_,max(v2) as v2_
   for (rws,cols) in (
       ('A','X') as A_X,
       ('A','Y') as A_Y,
       ('B','X') as B_X,
       ('B','Y') as B_Y
   )
);
```

Result:

```
   A_X_V1_    A_X_V2_    A_Y_V1_    A_Y_V2_    B_X_V1_    B_X_V2_    B_Y_V1_    B_Y_V2_
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2         90         25        112          4        117         46         32
```

Comment: Is there no way to make the headers hierarchical? I'm trying to duplicate the feel & readability of Excel-style pivot tables for users.

Either way, thank you very much on the "for" syntax: I looked at standard Oracle docs for pivot, and either I missed it or it wasn't covered, and I tried about a dozen things on my own with no luck.

Comment: @Jimthefourth _"Is there no way to make the headers hierarchical?"_ Onviously, no, since it's SQL. SQL can't produce hierarchical headers. It returns just simple table structure. But of course, you can emulate headers using UNION ALL: `select ' A ' C1, '' C2 from dual union all select 'X', 'Y' from dual`

Comment: or `select '  A  ' C1 from dual union all select 'X' ||' | ' || 'Y' from dual union all select '1' ||' | ' || '2' from dual`

Comment: But I'd suggest you to use report tools or return data as required XML structure

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was a clear "no", but I've just made the jump from a legacy SQL Server 2000 platform to Oracle 12g. I write SQL to feed my presentation layer in a few report creation systems, and so I'm exploring leap  forward in capabilities from SS 2000.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN RWS = 'A' AND COLS = 'X' THEN V1 END) AS AXV1,
  2         SUM(CASE WHEN RWS = 'A' AND COLS = 'X' THEN V2 END) AS AXV2,
  3         SUM(CASE WHEN RWS = 'A' AND COLS = 'Y' THEN V1 END) AS AYV1,
  4         SUM(CASE WHEN RWS = 'A' AND COLS = 'Y' THEN V2 END) AS AYV2,
  5         SUM(CASE WHEN RWS = 'B' AND COLS = 'X' THEN V1 END) AS BXV1,
  6         SUM(CASE WHEN RWS = 'B' AND COLS = 'X' THEN V2 END) AS BXV2,
  7         SUM(CASE WHEN RWS = 'B' AND COLS = 'Y' THEN V1 END) AS BYV1,
  8         SUM(CASE WHEN RWS = 'B' AND COLS = 'Y' THEN V2 END) AS BYV2
  9  FROM YOUR_TABLE;

      AXV1       AXV2       AYV1       AYV2       BXV1       BXV2       BYV1       BYV2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2         90         32        176          4        135         46         32

SQL>
```

Showing the multi-line headers must be taken care from application side.